# SABRE Single Branded Fare true

Tags: json, sabre

I´m using BFM Rest with the property SingleBrandedFare true. Why SABRE is returning multiple marketing airlines in a flyght?

What´s the property in json request I need to pass to SABRE return single Marketing Airlines per flyght?

The poroperty in json (OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ):

```
"PriceRequestInformation": {
            "TPA_Extensions": {
                "BrandedFareIndicators": {
                    "SingleBrandedFare": true,
                    "MultipleBrandedFares": false
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Branded fares are within one carrier if you look at Lufthansa for example a fare brand would be "Light","Classic","Flex" this has nothing to do with having only one operated flight at once.

What you are looking for i think is operator deduplication:

We use soap - therefore:

```
<!-- Optional -->
<!-- Repeat Factor=0-1 -->
<!--
Provides the capability to prefer itineraries that are unique if it comes to 
the operating flights. This is done by penalizing itineraries with 
duplicated operating flights.
<OperatingDuplicate Weight="10">
</OperatingDuplicate>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I solved the issue by passing the IndicatorOnline property to true.